# Passing Parameters in SSAS Reporting Action

Tags: action, ssas, reporting

I have a requirement to provide the detail information regarding Employee Sales shown in the cube in an SSRS report.

I have Employee Dimension, Transaction Dates and count of sales made. Requirement is to pass the Employee ID, Min Transaction Date, Max Transaction Date for the Employee to an SSRS report which will query the underlying fact /dimension table (NOT CUBE) and provide the detailed data.

I have set the Report Server And Path accurately and ensured that the parameter names match with that in the SSRS Report.

Just to establish the correctness of process I am trying to initially hard-code the EmployeeID,Startdate and EndDate in the SSAS Reporting Action Parameter List.

The Challenges I am Facing are as below :

1. I  pass the EmployeeId as UrlEscapeFragment(Cstr(7070707)) and the report action is available on the cube , and opens the report , However the SSRS report does not use this parameter supplied in the URL.
2. I am unable to pass a date value to the report , I tried the same Syntax and UrlEscapeFragment(Cstr(1-Jan-2016)) and this causes the report action to disappear when browsing the cube. I understand this is because there is a syntax issue.

Please bear with me if these queries are trivial as I am fairly new to SSAS and MDX and am struggling  to successfully establish a connection to the SSRS report from the cube.

Could anyone please help/advise.

Further down I guess I would need to pass these values dynamically but as a first step I am keen to establish the correctness of this all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i replaced the path with report server path instead of report manager , the parameter is being reflected in the report.  Also Date was updated as UrlEscapeFragment(Cstr("1"+"/1"+"/2016")) .

Comment: so it's working now? Can you post your comment as an answer and check the checkmark to mark it as the answer. This may help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

When i replaced the path with report server path instead of report manager , the parameter is being reflected in the report.

Also Date was updated as UrlEscapeFragment(Cstr("1"+"/1"+"/2016")) and was picked up.

This has now been replaced with dynamic values by using Dimension.Attribute.CurrentMember.Name.